# The existence of a function with application in finding bounded gaps between primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$'th  prime number. Can anything be said about the existence of a continuous differentiable function $f(x)$ and a positive constant $D > 0$ such that $$\frac{f(p_{n+1})}{f(p_n)} < D\cdot \frac{f^{\prime}(p_n)}{f(p_n) \log(p_n)}$$ for all $p_n$ with $n > N$ where $N$ is an arbitrary fixed positive constant? Further more the derivative must be monotone (increasing or decreasing). One can use eventually the fact that $p_{n+1} - p_n < p_n^\theta$ with $\theta > 0.525$ for $n$ large enough. The motivation for this is the following:

Supposing that such a function exists and suppose $f'$ is increasing. Also suppose that $p_{n+1} -p_n > D$. Then by mean value theorem $\exists c_n \in (p_n, p_{n+1})$ such that $$ f(p_{n+1}) = (p_{n+1} - p_n) f^{\prime}(c_n) + f(p_n) \geq D \cdot f'(p_n) + f(p_n)$$ $\forall n > N$ hence $$ f(p_{n+1}) \geq D \sum_{i=N}^n f'(p_i) + f(p_N)$$ Denote $S(p_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n f'(p_i)$ and (if I am not wrong, again) $S(p_n) \sim \frac{f'(p_n)}{\log(p_n)}$ Now this can be used to obtain a contradiction isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observe, if $f$ and $f'$ are positive and increasing,
$$\frac{f(p_{n+1})}{f'(p_n)}>p_{n+1}-p_n.$$
The right hand side is not bounded (there exist large gaps between primes), hence the left hand side is not bounded either. This contradicts your assumption, even when you omit $\log(p_n)$.

Comment: In fact it is even worse ... $\frac{f(p_{n+1})}{f'(p_n)} > p_{n+1} - p_n + \frac{f(p_n)}{f'(p_n)}$ :(

Comment: Sir, can you please have a look at this question (of mine) from Math SE? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313772/confusion-about-infinitely-many-bounded-prime-gaps

Comment: @CMarius: I looked at your SE post. The mistake is that you choose $D$ in terms of $n$ and $N$. In order to show infinitely many bounded prime gaps, you need to show the existence of some $D$ (a constant independent of anything else) for which the statement $\exists N:\forall n>N:p_{n+1}-p_n>D$ fails. In other words, you need to show $\exists D:\forall N:\exists n>N:p_{n+1}-p_n\leq D$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention sir. I really benefit from your expertise. But can $\frac{1}{p_N \cdot \left( Z_p(2,n+1) - C_2\right)}$ be proved to be  bounded above ?

Comment: @CMarius: Your fraction is certainly not bounded above, because the supremum of the denominator, i.e. $p_N\sum_{i>N}\frac{1}{p_i^2}$, is not bounded from below. Indeed, this product decays like $\frac{1}{\log p_N}$, harmonizing with the fact that the gap size $p_{n+1}-p_n$ is around $\log p_n$ on average. At any rate, don't expect a difficult number theory problem to be solved by simple analytic manipulations.

Comment: That is what I am obtaining for every function I can think about, not just $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @CMarius: Which is not an accident either. Once again, don't expect a difficult number theory problem to be solved by simple analytic manipulations. Instead, learn more number theory, e.g. study the works of Yitang Zhang, James Maynard etc.